# Why 0x8007000B on one Windows 10 Home PC and not on Another

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I have a program that is meant for mix platforms.  I have tested the same install able on 
Win 7 Pro 64 bit
Win 10 Pro 64 bit
Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit
Win 10 upgraded from  the above 8.1

Dozens of users have various flavors of Win 7.

But: I have one user that gets "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)" at the point where a particular DLL loads... actually that DLL loads and has an issue when a particular dependent DLL loads.

Given that I can point at a dozen 64 bit machines that work, I suspect some property of the Windows 10 Home Edition (that upgraded from a Win 7 home) PC.  I have a log file that demonstrates the same program ran OK before the Windows 10 upgrade.

What configuration settings on the user's PC should I be looking for?

Comment: If you have dozens of similarly configured machines and just one that breaks it might just be that a windows update broke things. To really diagnose the problem you would have to provide a lot more information and it's probably beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) is a useful tool for confirming whether or not the DLL that is failing to load is actually the DLL you were attempting to load.  Once you know for sure which DLL file isn't loading, compare it to other working systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is trying to load 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit executable (this can happen when LoadLibrary is used explicitly with e.g. a full path).

Another reason could be a damaged DLL (which might be actually the more likely case here because of the Windows upgrade). If the DLL is in Windows\system32, there is a good chance that if the particular DLL is renamed (e.g. to *.bad), the Windows protection system might recover the DLL to the proper version and resolve the issue.

Comment: I will test out a system restore to a pre-update to win 10 point.